# Regex 0's after decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex method that i'm trying to use to check for a decimal and only allow 2 numbers after it. So for example this should return true if you had 1.00 and false if 1.000 which it does but I also want it to return false if 1.3 or 1 
Not sure if I have something backwards or missing something here.

```
validateDecimal : function(value) {
            var regex = new RegExp(/^\d*\.\d\d$/);
            if (regex.test(value)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your regex works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7f1L92gL/. Also note you can change it to this: `/^\d*\.\d{2}$/` to avoid the repeated `/d`. If you have issues, I would check the console for errors, and also the documentation of your validation plugin.

Comment: You need to use: `var regex = /^\d*\.\d\d$/;` or else use `var regex = new RegExp('^\\d*\\.\\d\\d$');` (though not needed)

Comment: In your expression, you allow the absence of a number before the dot. If you want to check if there is one or many numbers, consider using the `+` like this `/^\d+\.\d{2}$/`

Comment: @ericb: please add more examples and return values for them, it's not clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I should have checked it more closely. I'm stupid I had another check before this and instead of || i used && so it wasn't returning correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to examples you provided, what you want is:

```
/^\d*\.\d{2}$/
```

Let's take it step by step:

1. \d* - match any digit and any amount of digits, so "1", "23", "3535" are matching
2. \. - literal dot
3. \d{2} - match only if there are two digits, so "00", "22", "56" are matching but "1" or "000" are not

You can test your javascript regular expressions [with this convenient online tool](http://scriptular.com/#%5E%5Cd*%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%24%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%221.00%22%2C%221.22%22%2C%221.0%22%2C%221.3%22%2C%221.55%22%2C%221.02%22%2C%225.00%22%2C%2234.00%22%2C%2232.55%22%2C%2274.0%22%5D).
Also [here](http://regexr.com/) is a great website that allows you to analyze your regex and learn more about it.

Comment: This then restricts the regex to only match numbers with a `0` directly after the decimal, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Quoting the question: `but I also want it to return false if 1.3`

Comment: Which it will do, but it will also *only* match numbers with one or two `0` after the decimal which is not what the OP requires.

Comment: Your example even shows that this does not work. It doesn't match `1.22`, `1.55` or `32.55`, and it also marks `1.0` as valid when the OP specifically states they *only* want values with two decimal places. I would suggest you read the OP again before you get downvoted.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: You're right about that, I misunderstood OP. I have updated my answer, thank you!

Comment: lol @ericb this answer is curious... it has exactly the same regex as the question

Comment: I had another regex before in my statement that was causing the issue. But I like the fact that this one uses the {2} so I picked it :)